# Using time dimension in OWB

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, oracle-warehouse-builder

I started to work with Oracle Warehouse Builder a few days ago, and I want to use some of the dates in a source table as a dimension.
I generated the time dimension with the wizard, but there is no way to connect the stored dates in my sourcetable to the generated time dimension. How should I do that?
I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your time dimension you should have the actual date time representation that Oracle uses in your source table. You simply join on that to get the DateKey.